# Remote ssh login does not respect pam umask

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, pam, umask

My server is on Ubuntu 22.04.1, and recently I discovered that the result of the `umask` command is `0002` instead of `0022` in an SSH session (non-root), which is odd because I have not messed with any related settings. I have checked and to the best of knowledge, my server should respect the PAM configurations, which sets `umask` to `0022`, but it doesn't.

Things I've checked:

1. `.profile` and `.bashrc` does not override `umask`.
2. `/etc/profile` and `/etc/bash.bashrc` does not override `umask`, but I have not checked the scripts in `/etc/profile.d`
3. `/etc/pam.d/common-session` has `session optional pam_umask.so`
4. `/etc/login.defs` has `UMASK 022`
5. `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` has `UsePAM yes`
6. `umask` in a `root` SSH session and `su -l root -c umask` in a non-root SSH session both yields `0022`
7. `umask` also yields `0002` with a freshly created test user
8. `sudo diff /root/.bashrc ~/.bashrc` does not yield any lines related to `umask`, `/root/.profile` only calls `/root/.bashrc`

FYI, I check the scripts by opening them with `vim` and type `/umask\c`.

I appreciate the help, I have exhausted all the possibilities I can find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason why, in `man pam_umask` under the `usergroup` option:

> If the user is not root and the username is the same as primary group name, the umask group bits are set to be the same as owner bits (examples: 022 -> 002, 077 -> 007). Note that using this
> option explicitly is discouraged. pam_umask enables this functionality by default if /etc/login.defs enables USERGROUPS_ENAB, and the umask is not set explicitly in other places than
> /etc/login.defs (this is compatible with login's behaviour without PAM).